# Serialize and Deserialize FormDataBodyPart in Jersey Java

Tags: java, rest, multipartform-data, jersey-2.0

I am having a situation where an api accepts the FormDataBodyPart as input and I need to store this somehow and then invoke some other Class method which accepts the FormDataBodyPart as input param.
I need some way to store this FormDataBodyPart object by serialization and then re-construct the FormDataBodyPart object and called the desired method of other class and pass it as input.
Any way I can do it.

Comment: I have a feeling this might be an [X Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info). Can you give some more context and provide some code. And maybe give a little more detailed explanation of the main goal you are trying to achieve. Serializing the FormDataBodyPart just seems awkward to me.

Comment: I have a file(logs.txt) stored in my file system. Now there's another method, say methodX(FormDataBodyPart file), that accepts the FormDataBodyPart as one of it's input parameter. I need to pass this file to the above method so need to construct an object of FormDataBodyPart.
The methodX then uses the file.getValueAs(InputStream.class). This method fails for me.
My goal here is to successfully construct an object of FormDataBodyPart using my file from the filesystem that I can pass to methodX as a parameter.

Comment: This does not really answer my question. I know that you want the FormDataBodyPart. But you're not explaining _why_? The fact that you need it outside the scope of how it's meant to be used (it seems like), sounds to me you may have a flawed design. You say you want to use getValueAs(InputStream.class). Why can't you just get a FileInputStream from the original file? Again I'll say that this seems like an XY problem.

Comment: Here the methodX is an existing api but it is time consuming operation. So the user rather hits my api which simply stores the file in the filesystem and and returns the success response. Now once this is done, there needs to be one method that can call the methodX and pass data. To do so I need to construct that object which can be accepted by the already existing methodX. I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Let me just explain to you what you have to understand. There are _two_ types of FormDataBodyPart, one is for incoming to the server and the other is constructed on the client-side to send to the server. With the latter, you will not be able to call getValueAs(). I'm assuming this is what you are trying to do, reconstructing the FormDataBodyPart. If I were you, I would not tie this methodX so tightly to Jersey and make it accept something else besides the FormDataBodyPart.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to do the same thing in order to re-construct the object of FormDataBodyPart here and I cannot change the methodX as these methods change dynamically who I call using reflection based on certain parameters.
Is there any way I can create the object of FormDataBodyPart as Jersey does it.

Comment: It's not that simple. You would need to look at the code for the [MessageBodyReader for MultiPart](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/blob/master/media/multipart/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/media/multipart/internal/MultiPartReaderClientSide.java). Here are [the parts](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/blob/56a5634fd4d8ef5857de612684e8761667269d51/media/multipart/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/media/multipart/internal/MultiPartReaderClientSide.java#L208-L230) you will be interestred in. Hint, you will need the entire raw multipart request in order to recreate the MIMEMessage